# 302 Moved Temporarily in jquery ajax in codigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting  302 Moved Temporarily error in jquery ajax in codigniter . Please let me know how can i solve this issue.

Some time it working fine but some time it gives issue.

I am unable to remove this error permanently.

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: base_url+'rep/rep/appointment_nonlunch',
           data: {office_id:id},
           success: function(response){ 
                $('.imgs').attr("src", base_url+"assests/UI/dashboard/images/logo_new-1.png");
                $('#img'+id).attr("src", base_url+"assests/UI/dashboard/images/logo_white.png");
               $('div').removeClass('selected_blue_div');
               $('#'+id).addClass('selected_blue_div');
               $('#Appdetails').html(response);                   

            }
        });



<div id="offices_input" class="min-height-offcie-1 simple-bdr-btm">
                     <?php 
                     if(count($office_data) != 0){ 
                        foreach($office_data as $office){ 
                     ?> 
                        <?php if($office->lunchpro_status == 0){ ?>                 
                            <div class="padding_bottom white_bg_maging_b_5 cursor-pointer" onclick="office_detail(this.id)" id="<?php echo $office->user_id; ?>" >
                                <div class="pading-ofc-24">
                                <div class="row">   
                                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-10">
                                      <h1><?php echo $office->office_name;?></h1>
                                      <p class="top-padding-p font_24px-color font_p_16_light"><?php echo $office->address.' '.$office->city.', '.$office->state.' '.$office->zip;?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-2">
                                        <div class="non-lunch-logo-img text-right">
                                            <img width="60%" alt="" class="imgs lunch-logo-15px" id="img<?php echo $office->user_id; ?>" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assests/UI/dashboard/images/logo_new-1.png">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                      
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php }elseif($office->lunchpro_status == 1){ ?>                        
                            <div class="padding_bottom white_bg_maging_b_5 cursor-pointer" onclick="office_nonlunch(this.id)" id="<?php echo $office->user_id; ?>" >
                                <div class="pading-ofc-24">
                                <div class="row">   
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                      <h2><?php echo $office->office_name;?></h2>
                                      <p class="top-padding-p font_24px-color font_p_16_light"><?php echo $office->address.' '.$office->zip;?></p>
                                    </div>                      
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                      
                        <?php }
                        }
                    }else{
                    ?>
                        <div class="text-center margin_top font_p_16_b">No Record Found<div></div></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
```

[image]

thanks

Comment: we can't find issue in your AJAX code, while you won't provide more details and server side code as well

Comment: I have update the code .....

Comment: This link might help you. It also talks about 302 issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473486/jquery-ajax-is-throwing-an-error-code-302-what-is-this

Answer (score 1):

Please try to check your server error logs, 302 is used for redirects.
Please make sure that you are redirecting the request from ajax some error page.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in header file in views folder :

```
    <script>
      var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
   </script>
```