# jQuery and AJAX response header

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, header, http-status-code-302

So I've got this jQuery AJAX call, and the response comes from the server in the form of a 302 redirect. I'd like to take this redirect and load it in an iframe, but when I try to view the header info with a javascript alert, it comes up null, even though firebug sees it correctly.

Here's the code, if it'll help:

```
$j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'url.do',
    data: formData,
    complete: function(resp){
        alert(resp.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
});
```

I don't really have access to the server-side stuff in order to move the URL to the response body, which I know would be the easiest solution, so any help with the parsing of the header would be fantastic.

Comment: if you're visiting this question in 2017 or later, please don't waste time with most of the existing answers. If your problem is same as OP, you've two options: 1) set up a proxy server which will `post` the original server and extract target-data and front-end JS will request this proxy-server for the target-data. Or, 2) change server's code to allow CORS.

Answer (score 214):

cballou's solution will work if you are using an old version of jquery. In newer versions you can also try:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:'url.do',
   data: formData,
   success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
   },
   error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
   }
  });
```

[According to docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the XMLHttpRequest object is available as of jQuery 1.4.

Comment: As of jQuery >= 1.5, it should be called [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), which is a superset of an XHR object.

Answer (score 145):

If this is a [CORS request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), you may see all headers in debug tools (such as Chrome->Inspect Element->Network), but the xHR object will only retrieve the header (via `xhr.getResponseHeader('Header')`) if such a header is a [simple response header](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology):

- `Content-Type`
- `Last-modified`
- `Content-Language`
- `Cache-Control`
- `Expires`
- `Pragma`

**If it is not in this set, it must be present in the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header) header returned by the server.**

About the case in question, if it is a CORS request, one will only be able to retrieve the `Location` header through the `XMLHttpRequest` object if, and only if, the header below is also present:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
```

If its not a CORS request, `XMLHttpRequest` will have no problem retrieving it.

Comment: @acdcjunior thank you it helped me also, after I have invested some time into finding out why there was no output in header response

Answer (score 39):

```
 var geturl;
  geturl = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://....',
    success: function () {
      alert("done!"+ geturl.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
  });
```

Comment: does not work for me. maybe I am doing the request to another site? ( cross site request using ajax)

Comment: For people who couldn't have it work like me. It's probably because you are doing a cross domain access which jquery does not use XHR. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Woked like a charm.. +1

Answer (score 18):

The unfortunate truth about AJAX and the 302 redirect is that you can't get the headers from the return because the browser never gives them to the XHR.  When a browser sees a 302 it automatically applies the redirect.  In this case, you would see the header in firebug because the browser got it, but you would not see it in ajax, because the browser did not pass it.  This is why the success and the error handlers never get called.  Only the complete handler is called.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E302.html

```
The 302 response from the Web server should always include an alternative URL to which redirection should occur. If it does, a Web browser will immediately retry the alternative URL. So you never actually see a 302 error in a Web browser
```

Here are some stackoverflow posts on the subject.  Some of the posts describe hacks to get around this issue.

[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

[Catching 302 FOUND in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373087/catching-302-found-in-javascript/1534604#1534604)

[HTTP redirect: 301 (permanent) vs. 302 (temporary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-vs-302-temporary-vs-permanent/1393298#1393298)

Answer (score 10):

The underlying XMLHttpRequest object used by jQuery [will always silently follow redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest) rather than return a 302 status code. Therefore, you can't use jQuery's AJAX request functionality to get the returned URL. Instead, you need to put all the data into a form and submit the form with the [`target` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#adef-target) set to the value of the `name` attribute of the iframe:

```
$('#myIframe').attr('name', 'myIframe');

var form = $('<form method="POST" action="url.do"></form>').attr('target', 'myIframe');
$('<input type="hidden" />').attr({name: 'search', value: 'test'}).appendTo(form);

form.appendTo(document.body);
form.submit();
```

The server's `url.do` page will be loaded in the iframe, but when its 302 status arrives, the iframe will be redirected to the final destination.

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE 2018 FOR JQUERY 3 AND LATER**

I know this is an old question but none of the above solutions worked for me. Here is the solution that worked:

```
//I only created this function as I am making many ajax calls with different urls and appending the result to different divs
function makeAjaxCall(requestType, urlTo, resultAreaId){
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: requestType,
            url: urlTo
        });
        //this section is executed when the server responds with no error 
        jqxhr.done(function(){

        });
        //this section is executed when the server responds with error
        jqxhr.fail(function(){

        })
        //this section is always executed
        jqxhr.always(function(){
            console.log("getting header " + jqxhr.getResponseHeader('testHeader'));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to write an existing header or this will return a null/undefined value. To get all response headers, use function `getAllResponseHeaders()`. [Check the docs for more info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders)

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
type: "GET",
async: false,
complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    var headers = XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders();
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks so much for the response, but that's still returning null. Any other ideas?

Comment: maybe you are using an old version of jquery.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to PleaseStand
and here is my other hack:

after searching and found that the "cross ajax request" could not get response headers from XHR object, I gave up.  and use iframe instead.

```
1. <iframe style="display:none"></iframe>
2. $("iframe").attr("src", "http://the_url_you_want_to_access")
//this is my aim!!!
3. $("iframe").contents().find('#someID').html()
```