# jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() won't return all headers

Tags: ajax, jquery

After a `jQuery.ajax()` call `jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()` won't return all the headers. The server responded with the following headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 64
Content-Type: application/json
X-My-CustomHeader: whatever
```

`getAllResponseHeaders()` returned only:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Example**

```
var request = {
  'url': 'http://api.someExternalDomain.com/resource/',
  'type': someMethod,
  'success': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
  }
};

$.ajax(request);
```

Comment: Hi Eddy. Can you post some code?

Comment: @adam: Sure! I just added an example.

Comment: This works for me on FF4 and Chrome. And I'm not entirely sure since you seem to be getting *some* data and your success callback function is triggered, but it might be the cross-domain request you're making that's the problem.

Comment: Also, what browser are you seeing this problem on? And have you tried logging the headers you get from a non-cross-domain request.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding: I am making cross-domain request.

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't expect that to work properly - unless you're using JSONP which it doesn't look like you're doing. I still don't see how you're getting *any* response at all given that it's a cross domain request. What environment are you running this in? Perhaps the solution might be to get rid of the CDR.

Comment: It also appears that even with JSONP, you will not get the response headers, only the data: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-response-headers-cross-domain

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors

Comment: This is the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header

Answer (score 15):

svenyonson called this out in the comments, but for me it was the answer, so I'm elevating it. **If you're doing CORS**, the server has to be explicit about what headers the client is allowed to read. If you want to read `X-My-CustomHeader` in javascript, then this header should be in the server response:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-My-CustomHeader
```

More detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors).

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Answer (score 7):

From jquery official website:

> At present, due to a bug in Firefox where .getAllResponseHeaders()
>   returns the empty string although .getResponseHeader('Content-Type')
>   returns a non-empty string, automatically decoding JSON CORS responses
>   in Firefox with jQuery is not supported.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/