# Having trouble getting jQuery AJAX response headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers, response-headers

This is what I'm trying:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://imgur.com/upload/',
  data: {
    url: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Phalaenopsis_JPEG.png'
  },
  complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
  }
});
```

I just get an empty string.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

These are the response headers I can see in Firebug:

```
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 02 Jul 2011 03:04:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: IMGURSESSION=asdfasdfasdfasdf; path=/; domain=.imgur.com
SERVERID=www4; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://imgur.com/ocuVX
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found one solution here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/the-shortest-image-uploader-ever/

```
function upload(url) {
  // Let's build a FormData object

  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("image", url); // Append the file
  fd.append("key", "6528448c258cff474ca9701c5bab6927");
  // Get your own key: http://api.imgur.com/

  // Create the XHR (Cross-Domain XHR FTW!!!)
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"); // Boooom!
  xhr.onload = function() {
    // Big win!
    // The URL of the image is:
    JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;
   }
   // Ok, I don't handle the errors. An exercice for the reader.
   // And now, we send the formdata
   xhr.send(fd);
 }
```

Obviously this solution requires a POST which means you need to use an API key. I couldn't find any way of getting a response with the API-keyless GET method.

The only way I could manage to do an upload without an API key was to go through YQL and get the final redirect URL from the diagnostics:

```
urlToImgur = (url, callback) ->
  upload_url = "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload?url=#{url}"
  $.ajax
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql'
    dataType: 'jsonp'
    data:
      q: "select none from html where url='#{upload_url}'"
      diagnostics: true
    success: (data) ->
      redirects = data.query.diagnostics.redirect
      image_url = redirects[redirects.length-1].content
      callback image_url
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it JSONP call? You won't get any headers then. Also see this: [jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() won't return all headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614735/jqxhr-getallresponseheaders-wont-return-all-headers)

Comment: Doesn't matter. If it is crossdomain, it automatically will go as JSONP. If you can tell what exactly are you trying, then maybe I can help better.

Comment: Oh right, didn't realise jQuery would do that automatically. What I'm trying to do is simply send a GET request to that URL with the url parameter. I then need to get the "Location" from the response headers. I've added the response headers I get to my question.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure client side solution? It'd be easier if you route your crossdomain call through a server side proxy. Also, I don't see your updated headers in the question, am I missing something?

Comment: I want to make a bookmarklet that will upload an image located at a specific url to an image host. imgur provides an api that allows you to upload an image directly from a url. The problem is I can't access the url that it returns.

Comment: You need to do a POST then. Take a look here, it might help: http://api.imgur.com/examples#uploading_js

Comment: @Mrchief let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1075/discussion-between-acorn-and-mrchief)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using > jQuery 1.5 and make sure you add crossDomain:true to your ajax attributes