# xmlHttp.getResponseHeader + Not working for CORS

Tags: jquery, wcf, authentication, wcf-security, cors

I have an asp.NET WCF on .NET 4. This service is used to authenticate users. We are submitting a username and password and then an HTTP Header should be returned with the authentication cookie included.  Using a locally hosted test page this is working correctly.  I am now attempting to access the header information cross domain.  I have installed my test page on a different machine and configured to call across to the WCF. The call is working and the 'data' reply in the call is correct.  However, I am unable to access the header information with either of the following:

```
alert(xmlHttp.getAllResponseHeaders());
```

or

```
alert(xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));
```

Using the debugger in IE and the 'Live HTTP Header' plugin for Firefox, I can see the header information is being returned.

In my global ajax page I am setting the response to handle CORS.

```
private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");


    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

}
```

This is the AJAX I am using to call the service:

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function(e) {
    var geturl;
    geturl = $.ajax({
        // type: "POST",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'http://10.0.4.66/AuthenticationService.svc/Login?Name=test&password=pwsd',
        // url: '../SecurityServer/AuthenticationService.svc/Login?Name=test&password=pwsd',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert('Error Occured');
        },
        crossdomain: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus, xmlHttp) {
            // alert(xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
            document.write(xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") + "<br/>");
            alert(xmlHttp.getAllResponseHeaders());
            alert(xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));
            var headers = '';
            var headerPair = xmlHttp.getAllResponseHeaders('wcfCookie').split("\r\n");
            var output = '';
            $.each(headerPair, function(key, line) {
                var parts = line.split(':');

                if (parts[0] == 'wcfCookie') {
                  ChocChip = parts[1]
                  return false
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Below is my header information grabbed from 'Live HTTP headers'

```
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2013 12:12:40 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: wcfCookie=8D38D5D6A0F138FEB595DD016F7694EDDF3E6757C82ED3D419F5047A5294974C1885487465CEC0A0BCC2B3802C7B03FF9F5370A05D4CCBDDDABCB1558C3816044BF4F78209BF38C6B1A7CAD34CD3C85C40B8515CFB1C2B2694BC78803D8DACB4
Content-Length: 65
Cache-Control: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
```

Answer (score 70):

**First, a little background:**

You are using `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, which specifies which *request* headers the client is allowed to *send*, but you are not specifying which *response* headers the client is allowed to *read*. To allow the client to read non-simple response headers, you need to use `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`. From the [HTML5 Rocks CORS page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors):

> During a CORS request, the `getResponseHeader()` method can only access simple response headers. Simple response headers are defined as follows:
>
> - Cache-Control
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
> - Expires
> - Last-Modified
> - Pragma
>
> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to use the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header. The value of this header is a comma-delimited list of response headers you want to expose to the client.

So, given that new information, you might do:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie");
```

...but there's more to it than that.

**Now, the actual answer:**

There's one more serious problem here: the XHR specification [explictily disallows reading `Set-Cookie`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders%28%29-method). That's because this is functionally a *cross-domain cookie-stealing attack*.

Suppose domain A makes a cross-domain request to domain B. When domain B sets cookies, it's setting domain-specific cookies *for domain B only*. Any attempt by domain A to read domain B's cookies is a violation of the same-origin policy for cookie access.

I don't know WCF, so I'm not the sure of best way to *actually* do what you want, but I'd guess the solution might be to pass an auth token not through cookies (e.g., a `X-WCF-Auth` header?) that domain A reads and then sets its own cookie.

Answer (score 2):

The browser's security policies might block your response because you have not set:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
```

If that doesn't help, try adding

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
```

to your `ajax` options might also be worth a shot.