# $httpProvider interceptor how to read all headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-get, angular-http-interceptors

I have an interceptor using $httpProvider as follwos (taken from Angular doc)

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
        return {
            'response': function (response) {
                // look for the antiforgerytoken and update dataService with the same.

                return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
});
```

using the debugger I see that this method is called on each response and when I look at the 'response' object pased I see only one header, namely the Accept-Header as shown below

[image: response object passed in the code]

When I look at the response packet in the chrome I see many more headers

[image: Network packet as seen in chrome]

My question is why am I not able to see all the headers in the response?

Specifically I want to read the cookie for AntiforgeryToken and store it, how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't Get Custom HTTP Header Response from Ajax getAllResponseHeaders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042439/cant-get-custom-http-header-response-from-ajax-getallresponseheaders)

Comment: @blueberryfields not duplicate, I am not using CORS and I am not required to do anything special at the server. In my case the server is already sending the header I need, I just don's seem to know the way to get to that information. I want to know how to read all the headers in an interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cookie `AntiforgeryToken` is a HttpOnly cookie and cannot be accessed from javascript. Can you check

See some details here http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/

Such cookies are mean for server exclusively.