# How to get content-length header value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I was trying to get the value of content-length header using jQuery.

```
var XHRObj = $.ajax({
    type:'HEAD',
    url:'https://www.udacity.com/public-api/v0/courses',
    success:function(data) {
        console.log( XHRObj.getResponseHeader('content-length') )
    }
});
```

It's getting as null. I checked the URL response headers. It has content-length header.

Comment: Maybe it's a case-sensitive issue? What about `data.length`? Might not be very accurate though.

Comment: Is it possible to get content-length header value without the json gets fully loaded? The size of my json is big, I just want to know the size from the header.

Comment: Oh right, I just noticed you are doing a HEAD request. Does it work with `Content-Length` instead of `content-length`?

Comment: I checked using Content-Length . It's coming as null.

Comment: Check all response headers then: ` `console.log(XHRObj.getAllResponseHeaders());`

Comment: I tried. I got error message as Uncaught TypeError: XHRObj.getResponseHeaders is not a function  Then, I tired console.log(XHRObj.getResponseHeader('Content-Length')); It's showing as null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88058/discussion-between-arun-prakash-and-minusfour).

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors