# How to view all response headers in ember with RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

My response headers look like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.7
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-On-Trial: 1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Vary: Origin
Date: Sun, 29 May 2016 00:37:31 GMT
```

But when I do a console.log(headers) in the RESTAdapter handleResponse function, all that is included is

```
EmptyObject {Content-Type: "application/json", Cache-Control: "no-cache"}
```

How can I access the X-On-Trail header or any other custom headers I may need?

I'm not sure if this matters but I am using ember-simple-auth. Does that strip out headers?

Answer (score 1):

I check sources. `.handleResponse` [is called from `.ajax`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.5.3/addon/adapters/rest.js#L775)

```
  ajax(url, type, options) {
    var adapter = this;

    var requestData = {
      url:    url,
      method: type
    };

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var hash = adapter.ajaxOptions(url, type, options);

      hash.success = function(payload, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        let response = adapter.handleResponse(
          jqXHR.status,
          parseResponseHeaders(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()), // try to check both in debugger
          payload,
          requestData
        );
```

So just try to stop at `parseResponseHeaders(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders())` line and check `jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()`. If it's ok - check `parseResponseHeaders()`

I'll be glad to help with debug, if you have public link for your project or if you can give link for any public project with REstAdapter

About striping - it skips headers which doesn't contains colons

P.S> Thx to @Vlad 
[xmlHttp.getResponseHeader + Not working for CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors)

["Access-Control-Expose-Headers"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers)

> Used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be > used when making the actual request.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: <field-name>[, <field-name>]*`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. What do you mean by " it skips headers which doesn't contains colons"? Are the headers supposed to be formatted a certain way?

Comment: It skip headers which has no ':' ( that's not about your case, just for information )

Comment: I did a `console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders())` in rest.js and it still only has the two headers. Any other ideas?

Comment: I figured it out with your help. The pointing me to the rest file and looking the jqXHR made me realize it wasn't an ember issue. I had to add the `"Access-Control-Expose-Headers"` header on my response with a list of headers to allow the client to view. Please add that part to your asnwer and I'll approve it. Thank you! See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors