# Unable to add custom header to response

Tags: ajax, django

I am unable to add a custom header to a response that is returned from render():

```
response = render(request, 'my_template.html', {'ctx1': 1, 'ctx2': 2})
response['My-Custom-Header'] = 'abc12345'

return response
```

This is a response to an Ajax request initiated using jQuery's `$.get()`.  On Chrome, the response has the template rendered properly, but it does not have the custom header.  If I print the `response` object before returning, I see that it has my custom header.

I thought the issue was because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14689355/2233706), so I added Django middleware to add a header to all responses:

```
class CustomHeaderMiddleware():
  def process_response(self, request, response):
    response['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'My-Custom-Header'
    return response
```

All my responses now have header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: My-Custom-Header`, but I still see this issue.

My request is local; I'm using the Django development web server.

If I send a non-Ajax GET request, whatever custom header I add in Django is visible in the response on Chrome.  So this issue seems to be limited to Ajax requests.

I am using Django 1.11.4 and Python2.

**[edit]**

If I capture the response in WireShark, I see that it does not have `My-Custom-Header`.  Furthermore, if I add a custom header to the response dictionary in the above middleware, the header shows up in Wireshark and is visible in Chrome.  So this seems to be a Django issue with responses to Ajax requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is unrelated to Ajax.  I was calling my view using [this template tag](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1568/).  The custom response headers are lost because of line 32 in that code.