# Angular 4 HttpClient Headers missing

Tags: angular

My problem is that I cannot get custom HTTP headers from my server into angular 4.
When I query the endpoint from another machine with CURL (screenshot 1), I get the header (`authorization`) but when I try accessing it via `res.headers.get` in Angular, I get null (screenshots 2 and 3).

The backend runs at `localhost:1337` and the frontend runs at `localhost:4200`

Screenshot 1:
[image: screenshot 1]

Screenshots 2 & 3:
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]

The used `postData` method:

```
postData<T>(url, body) {
  return this.http.post<T>(this.hostURL + url, body, {
    observe: 'response',
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.session),
  });
}
```

Comment: in order to get the full response in a get you must include {observe: 'response'} (see https://angular.io/guide/http) I don't know if when we use a post you can acheive it if we use the same tecnic

Comment: @Eliseo we use `observe: 'response'`...

Comment: @Armin post all the rlevant code, as text. And post the output you get, as text. Not sure why you expect the server to send an Authorization heaer anyway. That's a header that the client should send, containing the authorization credentials to access the protected resources. If the server needs to send an authorization token, it should send it back in the body.

Comment: @JBNizet added the postData method. We send the `authorization` header back and forth. They run out after some time and to prevent this when you are still working we refresh the token after every request.

Comment: This is *probably* your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors. But of course, with so few information about your code, it's only a guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors.

Comment: I am actually facing the same issue. Tried everything but no solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497390/angular2-service-request-header-response-for-x-pagination-page-count/47497617#47497617 please let me know if you found solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem:

I was missing the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` attribute in my server.
If you are using [Actionhero](https://www.actionherojs.com/), you have to add your custom headers to this attribute which has to be added at `httpHeaders` in `config/servers/web.js` (at least if you are using this config).