# angular2 service request header response for X-Pagination-Page-Count

Tags: angular, angular2-services, response-headers, yii2-api

[image]I am using angular2 service to get data response from yii2 api. In browser network tab it showing all required response but when I am trying to get it directly from component like

```
response.headers.get('X-Pagination-Page-Count')
```

Then it's not showing anything. except only showing content-type in response header via code. but can't get a function response. below is my service function.

```
getResponse(endpointUrl: string): Observable<any> {

    const url = url;

    return this._http.get(url)
        .catch((err) => this._handleError(err))
        .take(1)
        .map((res: Response) => res);
}
```

this is response image.

Comment: Do you send your requests to your own server? If yes, take a look if you set the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` attribute. It should contain your custom headers.

Comment: @Armin I tried all method like sending all options
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Pagination-Current-Page');
headers.append('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Pagination-Total-Count'); still getting same response, No Luck

Comment: Not sending, you have to add it to the backend.

Comment: Please check I have added response snapshot with query above.

Comment: for me, the problem wasn't with angular but with the server that answered my requests. Take a look at the backend and make sure you set the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` attribute.