# How to read custom HTTP Headers in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I have set custom HTTP Headers in my JQuery ajax request like this:

```
url:BASEURL+"path/to/my_api/endpoint.php",
headers:{
    'Authorization':'Basic',
    'App-Version':'1.3',
    'Key':'123456',
    'secret':'090909'
}
```

I would like to be able to read those in the target php scrip.
I tried :

`print_r(getallheaders());`

but the printed array is this:

```
Array
(
    [Host] => localhost
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Content-Length] => 153
    [Accept] => application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    [Origin] => http://localhost
    [X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (BB10; Touch) AppleWebKit/537.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.9.2372 Mobile Safari/537.10+
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [Sec-Fetch-Site] => same-origin
    [Sec-Fetch-Mode] => cors
    [Referer] => http://localhost/maxiko/application/test/index.html
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9
    [Cookie] => _ga=GA1.1.1030525951.1577774346; PHPSESSID=tm0ltrbt8op7bkksvh7mj9rdvs
)
```

it doesn't contain my custom key-value pairs. So how can I achieve this??

Comment: are you sure you are passing the headers? Try the developer console of the browser to be sure your header values are in the request

Comment: Positive. And to be precise, I am trying kind of trying to develop my own api and those fields were supposedly the API_KEY and SECRET and when read in the php code, they were supposed to be matched against registered API access credentials in my API database. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Try with `$_SERVER` array, it contain also the headers or with the `get_headers` function

Comment: see this question might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723138/ajax-response-cannot-read-all-the-headers-from-the-response

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding a  `print_r(getallheaders());` in one of my own projects and sent a `secret` header using postman. It printed out fine. If you are absolutely certain the header is being sent then my guess is that you are running php as a cli (from apache or nginx) and not as an apache module. Try looking in `$_SERVER['HTTP_SECRET']` it might already contain the header. But it's hard to provide a solution without knowing what you are running (apache, nginx) or seeing your config.

Alternatively, if this is running on the cloud then it might be that your cloud provider might not be forwarding the header. I'd check your cloudflare/aws/azure/etc... settings if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The headers might be transmitted differently to the PHP script depending on the PHP setup. (module, FPM, CGI). See [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19693), for example.

Try printing out `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV` and see whether they might be there instead.

In a pinch, you can use `SetEnvIf` to pass headers from one set to another:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
SetEnvIf "App-Version" "(.*)" HTTP_AUTH_VERSION=$1
...
```

It is not a best practice to rely on `getallheaders()` since (at least for now) it is an alias for `apache_request_headers()` and is, of course, Apache specific. Now while you might be happily using Apache now, you might want to keep your options open.