# refreshing data in http request header

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am writing a web page for the EvE online game using php and javascript. The EvE in-game browser sets some proprietary headers which include information about a characters location etc.

The web page is meant to draw a map showing the location of everyone connected to the web page. In order to track peoples movements the location information within the header needs to periodically update.

My current solution is to add a hidden iframe with a simple page refresh. This works, but the reloading of the iframe is visible on the status bar (it shows the url of the page being loaded). Ive seen other location tracking webpages that didnt show a url being loaded on the status bar and Im wondering if theres a more elegant solution to getting a fresh http request

---

Thanks for the advice guys. Im not too familiar with javascript or php so muddled my way through all the advice and finally used

```
setInterval(function() {
    GetUpdate();
    }, 5000
);

function GetUpdate()
{
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("POST", "http://myurl/parser.php", false);
    xhReq.send(null);
}
```

This seemed to do the trick without me confusing myself too much

Comment: Bro we just got monocled by CCP, are you familiar with javascript? How many users do you want to track?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use Ajax?

[JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater](https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater/)

[jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)