# How to read response headers from an ajax call in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am making an Ajax post request and I am getting the following as response headers:

```
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
**Cookie**  CAKEPHP=ooec5sah43c3f2doemdhvi61q2
Host    test.domain.com
Referer http://test.domain.com/test/login.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

I want to get the Cookie value. How to get it in jQuery? I know only how to get the JSON back.

Comment: Try this on So http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at getResponseHeader() method