# browser is not redirecting to redirect url in ajax request with cors

Tags: jquery, ajax, amazon-s3, cors, ajaxform

Hi all I am using [ajaxForm](https://github.com/malsup/form/) jQuery plugin to upload images directly to s3. Since it is an ajax submission I have configured the [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in s3 after reading the their [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html). So the upload is happening properly and the server is returning the redirect url to my browser with status code 303. I can see the response headers in my firebug. There I can see the Location header and it contains my redirect url too. When I copy paste this url on location bar everything works fine.

But the browser does not takes any action to this redirect. It should redirect to the redirect url as far as I know. From this post

[jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)

what I understand is browser won't give me this redirect url. I can't think of any work around for this problem please help if someone knows any solution.

Here is my code doing upload.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var upload_form = $("#img-upload-form");
   var submit_button = $("#img-upload-form input[type=submit]");
   var progress = $("#progressbar");
   var url      = window.location.href;
   if(upload_form != undefined){
      upload_form.ajaxForm({
           beforeSend: function(){
               submit_button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
           },
           uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete){
               progress.html("Uploading " + percentComplete + " %");
           },
           complete: function(response){
               progress.html("");
               submit_button.removeAttr("disabled");
               //window.location.href
           }
       });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Can you provide some code??

Comment: I have edited the Question to include some code

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it is related to the `Origin=null` in the request headers. Actually in my case the browser actually followed the redirect from S3, but my web application server was set to respond with another redirect, which was not followed.