# Is there any way to measure how much of a JSON file has loaded through jQuery so far?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, progress-bar

If a web page is loading a very large chunk of JSON, and displaying [a progress bar](http://jsfiddle.net/xXM2z/2415/) to assure the user that something is actually happening while he's waiting, is it possible to actually measure how much of the JSON has been downloaded at any given time, so that the progress bar can actually reflect reality, rather than a wild guess?

The total size of the file would be determined by [getting the `Content-Length` response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header).

Comment: take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836482/xhr-download-and-upload-progress

Comment: Yes, if the browser being used supports it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

If browser has support, you can track loading progress by means of this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

To know more about browser support of this feature, just take a look at: http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2