# 302 Redirect Header Location

Tags: ajax, redirect, header, location

I am submitting a form via an Ajax call to a 3rd party server. I have to include a return url as hidden data type in the form. Upon submit the 3rd party processes the data and redirects via a 302 response to the url which I specify.

Is there anyway for me to read the header location redirect url, I can see it in the header response in developer tools but can't read the data into a variable as follows:

```
$.ajax({
      url:'https://3rdparty.com/somescript.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:myVar,
      crossDomain: true,
      success:function(reply){
           alert(reply.getResponseHeader("Location"));
      }

});
```

Thank you in advace.

Alan.

Answer (score 1):

Change your success function to something like this

```
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
}
```

If that does not work, check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)

Comment: I changed the success as advised, but the error/failure function always evaluates as true rather than the success function...

Comment: It could be different things, I have updated it with a SO thread that is very helpful for your case.

Comment: I believe JQuery treats any response not within the 200-299 range counts as a failure. You can use this same function implementation in your `failure` function, or better yet, use `complete` instead.