# Replace image if resource is available and valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Using Javascript I can replace image by changing `src` parameter, such as

```
document.getElementById('image-id').src = 'new-image.png';
```

If I need change image dynamically when and only the new image is available and **valid**, how I need to adjust the above code to perform replacement only if browser is able to get the image?

Other words, if HTTP request for `new-image.png` ends with error (403, 404, 500, ...), or if the file is not a **valid image**, I want to keep the original image and do not execute the code, because otherwise browser shows no image.

Comment: Maybe you can start here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4236041/3315914

Comment: This appears to be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Comment: @rpax - Existence of file does not necessary mean that the file is a valid image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Common solution:*

```
$("<img/>")
  .load(function() {
    document.getElementById('image-id').src = 'new-image.png';
  })
 .attr('src', 'new-image.png');
```

---

*Clean solution:*

```
$("<img/>")
  .load(function() {
    document.getElementById('image-id').src = 'new-image.png';
    $(this).remove();
  })
  .error(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  })
  .attr('src', 'new-image.png');
```

---

Answer (score 3):

You can load the image separately and swap it in if successful:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
    // It worked, either replace `image-id` with this new `img` element:
    var oldImg = document.getElementById("image-id");
    oldImg.parentNode.insertBefore(img, oldImg);
    oldImg.parentNode.removeChild(oldImg);
    img.id = "image-id";

    // ===OR===

    // Just set `image-id`'s `src` (it'll come from cache, presumably)
    document.getElementById("image-id").src = img.src;
    img = img.onload = null;
};
img.src = "new-image.png"; // Important to do this AFTER hooking `onload` above
```

Answer (score 1):

as said in: [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript)

perform a ajax reguest on that file (this one done with jquery)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        // file does not exist
    },
    success: function()
    {
        // file exists
    }
});
```

Comment: Existence of file does not necessary mean that the file is a valid image!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Using Javascript:**

```
function imageExists(image_url){
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
 http.send();
 return http.status != 404;
}
if(imageExists('new-image.png'))//when image exists
   document.getElementById('image-id').src = 'new-image.png';
```

**Using Jquery:**

```
var image_url='new-image.png';
$.get(image_url)
.done(function() { 
  document.getElementById('image-id').src = 'new-image.png';

}).fail(function() { 
    // Image doesn't exist

})
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837750/1719752)**

Comment: For image, you don't really need to make any ajax request, onload event will be fired only on success

Comment: however if you use ajax you can find whether image exists or not without actually loading the image. Consider a 10 mb image file, you don't want to load it just to find if it exists or not. It depends on the use case, if your aim is to load the image anyways (like this question) then onload is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // The "callback" argument is called with either true or false
 // depending on whether the image at "url" exists or not.
 function imageExists(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
  img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
 img.src = url;
}

// Sample usage
var imageUrl = 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png';
imageExists(imageUrl, function(exists) {
 console.log('RESULT: url=' + imageUrl + ', exists=' + exists);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you could use:

```
function checkImage(img, src) {
    $("<img/>").one('load', function () {
        img.src = src;
    }).attr('src',src);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
checkImage(document.getElementById('image-id'), 'new-image.png');
```