# Get current URL from PebbleKit Javascript

Tags: javascript, pebble-sdk

I need to know the current URL from PebbleKit Javascript, my code is like follows:

```
Pebble.addEventListener("ready",
    function(e) {
        console.log("JS Ready");

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                req.open('GET', URL_MAIN, true);
                req.onload = function(e) {
                        console.log("Status returned: " + req.status); // status is 404
                        console.log(window.location.href);
                        console.log(location);
                        console.log(window.location.host);
                        console.log(document.URL);
                        console.log(document.baseURI);
                        console.log(window.location);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(Pebble)); // returns {}
                        //var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                        //console.log
                        //console.log(response.redirectUrl);
                        console.log(req.redirectUrl);
                        console.log(req.getResponseHeader('Location')); // This returns null
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // Nothing about the url

        }
        req.send(null);
    }
);
```

I tried some tests but no one returned me the current url. window.location.href and others returns this:

> pebble-js-app.js:13
>   file:///android_asset/jskit_startup.html?params=%7B%22loadUrl%22%3A%22file%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%5C%2Fdata%5C%2Fdata%5C%2Fcom.getpebble.android%5C%2Fapp_jskit_installed_apps%5C%2FTelepizza__1%5C%2Fpebble-js-app.js%22%7D

The use case is this:

1. I need to open the first URL (that has a 302 redirect).
2. Later, with this URL I can starting to make requests.

There is some way to get the current URL from Pebble Javascript?

Comment: What would the URL be in this context? The JS file is running on the user's phone, so the value returned from window.location.href is the URL of that file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `req.responseURL` field? I should contain the URL of requested page.

Also you can check answers to [jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header) if server responds with a redirect.