# Getting Date from http header response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

Okay so I can access the HTTP ajax response header using

```
xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
```

but it doesn't seem to get the Date with it, though its there:

```
 [Chrome]
**Response Header**
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:8092
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
**Date:Thu, 15 Jan 2015 16:30:13 GMT**
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
TotalCount:116
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

and the code only shows this :

```
[output on alert xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();]

Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
```

here's the the ajax call:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data,status, xhr) {

        displayNewData(data);
        alert(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());

    },
    error: function () {
    alert(url);

    }
});
```

Is there a way where I can get the Date in the response header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Helped :

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

[Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: It won't works as you can't access Date field using 'getAllResponseHeaders' or 'getResponseHeader()'

Chrome throw an error 'Refused to get unsafe header "date"'

Answer (score 7):

It might be the case you are making a [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) request and the headers are filtered out for security reasons.

See also similar question about [missing response headers in ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header).
The solution might be to set this HTTP header in the server response:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
```

Answer (score 1):

in your success method:

```
 success: function (data,status, xhr) {

    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Date'));


},
```

If response is a success

```
res=xhr.getResponseHeader('Date');
```

if response fails

```
res=data.getResponseHeader('Date');
```

Comment: I need to get the current time of the server which seems to be in the response Header

Comment: Check nothing, you didn't answer my question, and you deleted your comment telling me to give a parameter with type String for a javascript function.. I wish I can vote you down.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it before posting the question, it gives null, clearly because it wont get other details than the ones I mentioned in my question..

Comment: If my question doesn't deserve the vote, you shouldn't have had voted. If you were trying to be nice thanks.

Comment: I clearly see a date field in the response. Which one are you talking about? Otherwise just get the time from the server as part of json data response

Comment: Does it also give null in the console.log? It works for me. I know it sounds silly... But it's just about trying

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nginx, you can put below code in Nginx config file:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Date';
```

for real config example:

```
location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Date';
    root /usr/local/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

After restarting your nginx service, you can call getAllResponseHeaders again and it will show you the "Date".

[image]