# How long ago did I load a page?

Tags: javascript, time

Is there a way to get how long ago a page was loaded using javascript, without having first recorded the time to a javascript variable on page load? I'm hoping to create a scriptlet (javascript bookmark) that I can run on any web page and have it output how much time has passed since the browser loaded the page.

All of the "time spent on a page" solutions I've found so far rely on recording the time when the page first loads, which requires either access to modify a site, or a browser plugin. Is there no document property that stores when the page was loaded (started, finished, etc.) which can be accessed in javascript?

Comment: You can get the Date from the HTTP header. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968368/getting-date-from-http-header-response

Comment: You can get timings from `window.performance.timing`. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript#14878493) for more details :)

Comment: Arkantos beat me to it. It looks like that API was removed in iOS 8.1 though! That's pretty disappointing.

Comment: @Katana314 So that means iPhones + iPads don't have that info, but PC browsers do?

Comment: @Katana314.. thanks for mentioning that :) As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing), it's removed in iOS 8.1 but there're still good range of browsers that support it

Comment: iPhones & iPads with chrome browsers still do ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd`:

```
> performance.timing.loadEventEnd
1424280020354
```

`window.performance.timing` provides timestamps for the following page load lifecycle events, in order:

- navigationStart
- unloadEventStart
- unloadEventEnd
- redirectStart
- redirectEnd
- fetchStart
- domainLookupStart
- domainLookupEnd
- connectStart
- connectEnd
- secureConnectionStart
- requestStart
- responseStart
- responseEnd
- domLoading
- domInteractive
- domContentLoadedEventStart
- domContentLoadedEventEnd
- domComplete
- loadEventStart
- loadEventEnd

Source: [Navigation Timing API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing)

The Navigation Timing API is currently supported by most modern browsers. Exceptions: Safari < 8 on OSX, Safari on iOS and Opera Mini. - [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing).