# How to get date from XHR header in Angular2?

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

I want to get a date from XHR Header Reponse.

[image: Response Header]

I tried to add '{observe: 'response'}' as options

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getAllTemps() {
        return this.http.get<AllTemp>(this.endpoint, {observe: 'response'});
      }
```

but then my response looks like this: 
[image]
There is no souch key as I expected.

Any ideas how to solve this? Maybe there is another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Date from http header response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968368/getting-date-from-http-header-response)

Comment: @Ploppy he asked in the `Angular` way

Comment: @chaitanya then you didn't read the linked answers

Comment: Theoritally same concept. But method used to get the headers are different

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `Date` from `XHR-Header` in your Angular application. First your `back-end application` should send that header in the response using `res.set()` if it's `node.js`. Same way in other server langauge.

You can get `header` in the following way

```
getAllTemps() {

    return this.http.get<AllTemp>(this.endpoint, { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe(res => {
        // getting all the response headers provided by server application
        console.log(res['headers'].keys());

        // Getting header with key
        console.log(res['headers].get('Date'));

          });
  }
```

> **Note**: While getting header by key and if your server-application didn't send header it'll log `null`

find following stackblitz example.
[working stackblitz demo with dummy url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcapsw)

Comment: First check whether you're having `Date` header in the response using  `console.log(res['headers'].keys());`

Comment: I use PHP on my backend. I tried to add header 
`header('Time: '. $current_date = date('H:i:s'));`
but it still don't show me headers.

Comment: There is no problem in `Angular` code which I provided. You're not setting the `Date` header correctly in your `php`. I think it should be header `('Date':...)`. Also check my first comment, to verify you're getting `Date` in the log array.

Comment: @MateuszDaniluk added the stackblitz demo, which gets `expires` header. As that API not exposing `Date` header I given example with `expires`.