# Struggling getting Content-disposition in JavaScript by Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

First of all, I want to say that I'm a beginner and am trying to solve a task involving downloading an Excel file from the backend in a project.
Front-end : React & Redux & Rtk Query
Back-end: Java & Spring

The problem I'm facing is that I can't use RKT Query to download the file because of caching. Therefore, I have decided to retrieve the file using the Fetch API.

However, I'm struggling with the fact that the name of the file should be delivered from the backend, and as I understand it, this requires the **Content-disposition** header to be present. When I make a simple fetch request and check the Network tab in the dev tools, I can see the Content-disposition header. But when I try to log the response in the code, the Content-disposition seems to be missing.

The code is simply a fetch API method.

This is the first time I need to get a name from the backend, and to be honest, I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

I have **included** an image of the Response Headers from the dev tools, along with what the console.log output looks like.

[image]

That is the response from fetch API
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the Fetch API and Cors 'disable' some headers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the filename from a file downloaded using Javascript Fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286221/how-to-get-the-filename-from-a-file-downloaded-using-javascript-fetch-api)

Comment: @HereticMonkey ahh you have totally right, my bad I gonna remove the image and provide more text information.