# How to get Buffer data from PDF using FastAPI Python

Tags: python, pdf, buffer, fastapi

I am getting an error while reading the pdf file data in FastAPI
Code :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/')
async def storeFileData(file:UploadFile):
    content  = file.file.read()
    return {"ok":True,"content":content}
```

Error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

I tried using the above code to get buffer data from the pdf file, But I am unable to get data

Comment: Further related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728386/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76195586/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197700/17865804)