# .zip file gets corrupted after downloading from FastAPI Server

Tags: python, fastapi, fileresponse

I have to **download .zip file** (created using python shutil library) using **FastAPI Server.**

Code to create .zip file

```
shutil.make_archive(base_name = base_name , 
                      format = 'zip', 
                      root_dir = 'fileName.zip')
```

Here is my route method.

```
@app.get("/_archiveFiles_download", response_class = FileResponse)  
async def archiveFiles_download(request: Request):  
     archiveFilePath = 'fileName.zip'  
     return FileResponse(path = archiveFilePath)
```

And JavaScript function

```
   // function to download archive file 
    function downloadZipFiles() {  
        $.get("./archiveFiles_download").done(function (data) {  
            console.log(data)  // prints garbage in console window  
            // Create an anchor element for the download link  
           const link = document.createElement("a");  
           const blob = new Blob([data1], { type: "application/x-zip-compressed" });
           const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
           link.href = url;
           link.download = 'fileName_Download.zip'; // Set the desired file name 
           link.click();         // Clean up the temporary URL 
           URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
       });  
  }`
```

`console.log(data)` prints garbage data in the inspect console.
also downloaded file is corrupted.

*Same thing happens if I send **.txt** file having some **special characters**.*

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers could also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195901/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804)

Comment: **Read** tag descriptions before you use tags. From [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag."