# Broadcasting solutions / encoders/ decoders

Tags: streaming, broadcast, live-streaming, encoder

So I've been digging around for a couple days in the broadcasting/streaming grounds and I encountered so many questions, especially with the encoders and decoders.

I need to find the **cheapest** and best solution for live streaming/ broadcasting. So far I am using OBS as my encoder, but as far as I know it encodes in the RMTP protocol and it uses flash players to stream the broadcast. And I do not want that. I want to use the HTML5 player (like the ones WOWZA, nanoCosmos) uses and I need the latency to be as low as possible. My questions would be:

1. Can I use OBS for low latency? Because I have tested out OBS with wowza streaming cloud and the latency was **huge**.
2. How to get rid of the flash players using OBS? If it is not possible what other cheap/free encoders there are, that would do the job?
3. What other things I need to think about it? So right now I need a proper encoder, CDN and a player (but if I am using one of the commercial players, usually they provide their Cloud CDN).

### EDIT:

Since it should be an auction house live streaming I need the latency to be as low as possible.

- The latency I need to achieve is no more then 2s.
- Audience: up to 500
  people.

Comment: What does "low latency" mean to you, specifically?  Is 3 to 10 seconds low enough?  Or are you talking about video conferencing style video where less than 500 milliseconds is desirable?  How many people do you need to stream to?  You also mention you need it to be cheap... are you absolutely sure all viewers need low latency?  You should realize that there are very real tradeoffs in terms of quality and cost.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457972/low-latency-2s-live-video-streaming-html5-solutions/37475943#37475943

Comment: I edited my post, but here's more details: Since it should be an auction house live streaming I need the latency to be as low as possible.
The latency I need to achieve is no more then 2s.
Audience: up to 500 people. So far I also tested out nanoCosmos services but they are really pricey but so far the best I tried. So maybe someone who has more experience in this field and knowledge can advice me if there's other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure you need latency that low, you need WebRTC.  While it is possible to achieve latency this low over regular HTTP Progressive streaming, your application will benefit from being able to drop chunks if they don't come in time, encode in a low quality low latency mode, decode in a low latency mode, and everything all the way through.

You're going to need a provider that supports WebRTC distribution, and they aren't cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SLDP](https://softvelum.com/sldp/) which is WebSocket-based protocol for sub-second latency. We have [SLDP Player](https://softvelum.com/player/) for HTML5, android and iOS which allows playback on all major platforms.