# WebRTC two-to-many

Tags: architecture, video-streaming, webrtc

i have to broadcast a 2-to-many, using a scalable WebRTC media server able to record the streams too.

I don't want to use something like the Janus Room Call solution (https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videoroomtest.html), because in my case the delay between the 2 publisher is more crucial than the delay with the subscribers.

So it's a one-to-one communication (not peer to peer, there is a media server), and i want to broadcast those 2 streams, is that possible?
I guess it is, but i would know if there is something like this or if i have to customize a media server.

Ty in advance

Comment: See my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37475943/362536  Different question, but essentially same solution.  Since you don't actually need low latency to the viewers, you can optimize for quality there, and potentially re-use existing services like YouTube and Facebook and save a ton of money.  At a minimum, you can use standard CDNs for the primary distribution.  I also have a solution I've built for this, which can be licensed to you if you don't want to build it yourself.  Please contact me if you're interested... brad@audiopump.co.