# How do I Stream Realtime Video to a Website

Tags: video, video-streaming, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I have a LEGO Mindstorms robot running Debian and Python. The robot can be controlled using a web interface to move, steer, turn on lights, etc... Currently I use this web interface to control the robot while I'm in the same room. I want to add a camera to the robot so I can control the robot remotely.

I have looked into adding a camera to the Mindstorms Brick, but the Brick does not have enough resources to stream a video source. So I don't think this route is possible.

Does anyone know of a method to stream live video content from a source from a Mindstorms Brick to a website? If not, maybe another source (it must be wireless, like an iPhone, GoPro, etc...) directly to a website.  It's quite important that there is as little delay as possible.

If there is a better forum for asking this questions please let me know, I looked around and could not find one.

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457972/low-latency-2s-live-video-streaming-html5-solutions/37475943#37475943

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar solution for controlling RaspberryPI robot with camera, please read  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70675353/17679565).

Generally you need some UDP video streaming transport, like WebRTC or SRT.