Youtube Live Broadcast
I am creating a project and in my project we are doing live streaming. The issue is - I am using Chime and then middleware ECS and then calling the Youtube API. When time logs were checked it came out that Chime is giving response in .5 - 1 seconds to the middleware but then when the live stream starts the user is experiencing the lag of 18-25 seconds in the live streaming from one person to the another. We have already tried removing the middleware and connecting Chime to YouTube API directly but this increased the lag. Suggest a solution for the same please.
Explained the method above

If you care about low latency, don't use YouTube.  YouTube is for streaming to thousands of people, not for low latency 1:1 video.  Somewhat relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37475943/362536
