# Why Custom Header message is not coming in oData Service call response in SAPUI5?

Tags: http-headers, sapui5

I have Custom message header code which is written in SAP ABAP where I was able to get the Custom message header in Gateway Client

[image]

I can see the Highlighted part of SAP Gateway Client but when I am calling the service from SAP UI5 application I do not find the Response Headers with my custom message.

[image]

Please help me, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you check for the header in network tab?

Comment: Yes cschuff,see in my question i am showing headers what i am getting,but its not having message what i have highlighted in Gate way Client screen.

Comment: Nope. I mean: Did you check the actual headers shown in network (not in preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create an OData model in the Manifest.JSON file and access the OData model in the controller and Call your service. Doing this you can find the Header message in the Response Headers.
In the Controller, you can code this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("yourODataModelName used in Manifest").

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while performing an update using a JSONModel. 
If you add a custom header to your response, you may have to indicate this with the "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" header. Please see 
[jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)
for a more detailled explanation.

Something like the following should do :

```
response->set_header_field( name = 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' value ='message' ).
```