# Redirect AJAX response URL from PHP header

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have an AJAX POST that is sending back a successful response from my PHP file `newPNRsubmit.php` :

```
if(isset($_POST['ticketentry'])){
            $_SESSION['ticketEntry'] = 1;
            header("location: pnr-details?id=".$pnrid);
        }
```

However I would like to use the AJAX response that I am receiving into `window.location`

This is the response:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "https://example.com/pnr-details?id=240".
```

This is my AJAX structure:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "newPNRsubmit.php",
 data: {
 bookingdate: bookingdate,
 airline_id: airline_id
},
 cache: false,
 success: function(data, url) {
 $('#NewPNRModal').modal( 'hide' );
},
 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
 console.error(xhr);
 }
 });
 return false;
```

How can I correctly parse the URL that I am receiving into `window.location` ?

UPDATE: This is the response from console tab. The second `GET XHR` is showing the link I need for `window.location`. Should I update the header location to send `JSON` data in my `PHP` file in order for this to work?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either return a URL in the body instead of a header, or get the header like so:

```
success: function(data, URL, jqXHR) {
  window.location.href = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("location");
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution too, but I was wondering if the browser won't simply follow the `location` header and we won't see it.
Well, it seems that you can only read it if you add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location` in your CORS, according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444439/653182

Comment: @htmhell I did it but it is redirecting now to a NULL url

Comment: Are you sending the request from the same domain? If not, it's probably CORS problem. In any case, try to `console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());` and see what's the result.

Comment: And what's the output you see on the console?

Comment: @HTMHell this is the output: 

`cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 25 Jun 2021 14:25:10 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: LiteSpeed
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.34
x-turbo-charged-by: LiteSpeed`

Comment: @Leb_Broth it looks like the issue is at the server not returning a `location` header. You can validate that using the browser's dev tools under the Network tab. In that case you should find out why isn't the server returning this header. One option that I can think of is that you output something before or after you call the `header` function. try  to `die();` right after the `header` call, and make sure there's no output at all before. (also make sure there isn't any blank spaces before `<?php` tag)

Comment: it seems we are looking into the POST request headers while we should look into the GET response headers. The console.log is showing the POST headers and after the console output i can see the GET response with the link I want, that is returning from the PHP header. I will try the tips in your last comment.