# jquery How can i get headers key value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, response

I want to get headers `key` and `value` in response. In the image below you can see header response data. There is a key named `documentname` recieved from server in header.

[image]

How can i get this key and value in jquery ?

**Update**

I am using `Syncfusion` Component and headers is not ajax call response :

```
<ejs-uploader id="UploadFiles" success="onuploadSuccess" autoUpload=false></ejs-uploader> 

<script>
    function onuploadSuccess(args){
        console.log(args.response);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)

Comment: @strd0x The question has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving a non standard string in your `object.headers`.  That being said you'll have to manually tear it down.

1. Split it based on *newline* `\r\n`
2. Filter the array and search for `documentname`
3. Pluck the element you want (should be the ONLY element) --> `[0]`
4. Split on `:`  (space included, unless you want to `trim()`, Either works here)

You will end up with

```
["documentname", "sdfasfjhkjsdfhkjsdf.png"]
```

You can go a step further and break them down to `key` and `value` -- Then you can do whatever you wish with them ... Create an object, or handle them individually as strings.

I recreated `my_object` to provide a working example..  Just replace the `my_object.headers` with `args.response.headers`.

```js
const my_object = {
headers:"content-length: 0\r\ndate: Wed, Dec 6 2023 22:28:37 GMT\r\ndocumentname: sdfasfjhkjsdfhkjsdf.png\r\nserver: Kestral\r\n", 
readyState:40, 
statusCode:200, 
statusText:"",
withCredentials:false
};

const docArr = my_object.headers
    .split('\r\n')
    .filter(element => element
    .includes("documentname"))[0]
    .split(': ');
    

console.log(docArr)

const key = docArr[0];
const value = docArr[1];

console.log('key is: ' + key + ' and value is: ' +  value)
```