# jQuery Ajax request with a redirect not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I'm trying to connect to a web service that has the following setup:

1. Send credentials to `domain.com/logincheck`
2. Server redirects request to either `domain.com/loginOk.xml` or `domain.com/loginBad.xml` which contains the details of the login attempt (successful = token, error = error string)

When excuting the request, I see the request (POST) in the "Network" tab (Chrome Dev Tools) which shows the 302 redirect, and than an attempt to access the `loginOk.xml` (GET) but the status of the request in the "Status Text" column is shown as `(canceled)` as if it just initiated a request but dropped it as soon as it's started.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request

Comment: @m90 I'm aware of this, doesn't help me at this point

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a case of chrome blocking insecure content from loading -- albeit not an obvious one.

I'd guess that your page was accessed using HTTPS and that the redirect to `loginOK.html` was actually targeted to a HTTP URL. So, even though the original `POST` request was to a secure page, the redirect was an insecure content and thus it was blocked (or `canceled`, as chrome called).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6967007/631114