# Zend Framework: init call to action via Ajax results in redirect. Subsequent calls are successful

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework, jquery

So I haven an interesting issue that I hope other have stumbled on (and solved) before.

I have set up a 'change my password' option for users on this particular application where if a user were to forget their password they can request to change it. I send them an email with a hash embedded in a link that directs them to a simple 'change password' screen.
[image]

[image]

Once the user clicks on the update button - I call the appropriate controller-action via ajax and the server processes various things such as updating the password,  deleting the token and redirecting the user.

Here be the ajax tied to the update button:

```
updatePassword: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/side-panel/update-password',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                token: $('input[name=token]').val(),
                id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
                new_password: $('input[name=new-password]').val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                kts.show_loader('show');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                kts.show_loader('hide');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

The first time the user were to click the button - the console shows this:

[image]

Notice the URL below and the Network entries in the upper left:

`"http://code.kenstowell.local/".`

It makes a call to the appropriate action, but returns a 302, and then redirects to the base URL of the site.

The second time the user were to click the button it calls the controller-action as it should.

[image]

Notice the  URL here: `"http://code.kenstowell.local/index/update-password"`

The real problem here is, on the first call/button click - the server-side code actually get's processed, but the XHR object returns a failure.

I apologize if this is information overload. Please let me know if you need more code/samples provided. Any help appreciated.

Ken

Comment: I falsely assumed that SO would enable you to click on an image and see it full size - I will provide remote urls to full size versions here shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this little gem:

[Catching 302 FOUND in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373087/catching-302-found-in-javascript)

Apparently, ajax doesn't handle server side redirects well.