# How do I intercept a 302 redirect

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, http-status-code-302

Hello I want to debug a website and see whether it is still sending data after a redirect request. Is there anyway that with my browser I can ignore the redirect request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catching 302 FOUND in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373087/catching-302-found-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

I was trying to do this in a userscript using `window.location.replace()` , but it seems the DOM can't access the 302 URL because it doesn't have response content that generates a page.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406899/4364036 for W3C explanation.